# Why is the number of isotopes of an element bounded?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements, isotopes

Is there a known reason why any given element has finitely many isotopes? Here I mean both stable and unstable isotopes.

If we know this, do we have a reason why, for a given element, are the isotopes limited to that particular number?

Comment: An infinite number of isotopes would require that some of them have extremely large (like macroscopic) mass.  To get "infinitely many, you'd need some that had arbitrarily large numbers of neutrons.  Surely that cannot be what you meant to ask with this question?

Comment: well, I dont mean actual infinity, I mean what is the upper limit and why is there one. Also for an element with n protons do we always get isotopes of the form `n, n+1, ..., n+m` for some `m`?

Comment: Why do you think a nucleus with a very large or very small neutron/proton ratio would be stable? Consider: tritium (1p + 2n) is unstable, but helium-3 (2p + 1n) is stable.

Comment: Well, I'm not asking about stable isotopes, just isotopes that can exist. Like when we say Hydrogen has three isotopes with 0, 1 and 2 neutrons. Wha tis the physical reason we don't have a 4th with 3 neutrons? What breaks down?

Comment: Are you familiar with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula)?

Comment: Search term: [neutron/proton drip line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_drip_line).

Comment: You may find this related question helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323350/123208

Comment: There *are* heavier H isotopes, but they fall apart pretty quickly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen As well as articles on the isotopes of each element, Wikipedia has several lists of nuclides you may enjoy exploring, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclides & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_nuclides

Comment: Not enough thanks to go around. Would the following statement be true "In theory there is no limit to the number of neutrons you can add to a nucleus, it would just be unstable and gain mass but in practice the half life would be so short as to make it indistinguishable from it's daughter nuclide(s)"

Comment: I'm definitely no physicist, but I think that if you manage to put enough neutrons together, you end up with a black hole. That would give you a hard (finite) limit.

Comment: @MartinArgerami If we talk about neutron stars, they contain a healthy percent of protons and electrons in an equilibrium state with the neutrons. But at some neutron star layer, one may find very neutron-rich nuclei that are unable do decay simply because of the degenerate state of both neutrons and electrons (and maybe even protons). The decay energy is not enough to out the decay product at the first available energy level.

Comment: @fraxinus I think that was not about neutron stars, but adding neutrons *to the one nucleus*...

Comment: @fraxinus: as far as I can tell, if you put enough baryonic matter together, regardless of what it is, you'll end up with a black hole. So there has to be some (crazy big) number of neutrons such that if you put them together you end up with a black hole.

Comment: @MartinArgerami for the upper limit - absolutely correct, it even does't have to be baryonic. My point was that it is not the same element anymore as if you add enough neutrons on the pile, some of them happen to transform into protons... even in a neutron star.

Comment: @fraxinus: I see. That probably gives a much much lower limit, then.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a good question -- after all, if there's no extra Coulomb repulsion penalty for adding more neutrons, unlike for protons, why can't nuclei have lots of neutrons?

One model for the nucleus we use is called the Semi-Empirical Mass Formula (SEMF), which has a bunch of terms describing the energy contributions to the nucleus.  [See wikipedia for the full formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula).  The main term that answers your question is the "Asymmetry Term", given by
$$a_\text{A}\frac{(N-Z)^2}{A}$$
where $a_\text{A}$ is some constant we can find empirically, $N$ is the number of neutrons, $Z$ is the number of protons and $A=N+Z$ is the nucleon number.

This is a penalty term in the energy of a nucleus.  If there is a large difference in $N$ and $Z$, this term is large.  If $N$ is similar to $Z$, the term is not as large.  The rational for this is the Pauli Exclusion Principle, which tells us identical particles cannot occupy the same energy state.  If we're adding lots of identical neutrons, we must put them in different energy states.  We can get a cheaper energy cost by filling in some protons instead for a given nucleon number $A$.

To answer your question in the comments:  why do isotopes often have more neutrons than protons, I think the answer there is it *is* somewhat favourable to add nucleons to the nucleus, because that increases the strong force present, but its cheaper to use neutrons than protons, at least for cases where the ratio $N/Z$ does not deviate too far from 1.

Comment: I assume there is a experimental correlation whereby half life decreases as `N/Z` increases but is there any threshold there where N/Z is so high the nucleus cannot form?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a question of whether a nucleus can or cannot form, more a question of how many energetically more favourable alternatives there are for the bunch of protons and neutrons to form.  As mentioned in another answer, there’s no reason 9H cannot exist, but its energy for the given value of A would be high and it would want to decay very quickly.

Answer (score 7):

In the comments you clarify your question by asking, as an example, about hydrogen isotopes.

If you look at [a Table of Nuclides](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html), you will see that there are at least 7 hydrogen isotopes which have been identified so far. There are links attached to each entry in the table that give data on the reactions for creating these exotic nuclides.

You can see that the He-3 through He-10 have been identified, C-8 through C-22. At the extremely neutron-rich ends, the halflives are extremely short, and neutron emission is prevalent.

It seems, based on the experimental data, that the only restriction on neutron-rich isotopes of any element are the experimental ability to make the nucleus long enough/in sufficient number to get repeatable measurements to demonstrate they have actually been made.

EDIT: As pointed out in a comment, there most likely is a limiting halflife. [Check out this question and answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286753/physical-limit-for-the-shortest-possible-half-life).

There's no reason to assume that H-8 and H-9 won't eventually be formed and identified. It will take a lot of ingenuity, patience, and money.

Comment: There has to be a lower limit to the half-life, though. As mentioned in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/468493/123208 "the theoretical limit on very short half-lives is the fact that information cannot travel faster than the speed of light. Obviously, a nucleus must be bound before we can discuss its half-life. But it makes no sense to say that a nucleus is bound if it decays before all of its constituent protons and neutrons "know" that it has formed".

Comment: @PM2Ring I see the point made there so I guess there is some type of bound. But there is no nuclear model predictor for when that limit is reached. Would it be H-13, H-20, ? I expect it might be before those, but I don't know of a model to calculate what adding another neutron will do.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's also interesting to me that the chart I linked (presumably, the latest information available) doesn't have He-2, which some consider a real intermediate step in the proton-proton cycle, just before it decays to H-2. I guess no one on Earth has measurably identified He-2.

Comment: @PM2Ring Answer has been edited. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to measure the half-life of He-2 (aka diprotium). It's hard to form it, and even when you do manage to make it, it almost immediately falls apart, which doesn't give the slow weak force much time to convert it to deuterium. As I recently said [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43908/16685), the probability of that conversion is of the order of $10^{-26}$.

Comment: It's not the half life. It's binding energy of the extra neutron. As you add neutrons the amount of binding energy for the last neutron decreases. Eventually the binding energy of the last neutron becomes nonnegative. This is called the drip line (because the last neutron "drips off.") There is also a proton drip line. As to an upper bound if you stay close to the line of stability. For any given number of protons there are drip lines to either side. But somewhere between 137-250 protons the repulsion is so huge that no number of neutrons makes the binding energy of all nucleons negative.